# Check if twisted return value is a Deferred

Tags: python, twisted

In [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) there are a few api's that can return a [`Deferred`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.defer.Deferred.html).  Is there a quick way to test if the returned value is a `Deferred` or it is actually the return value.

I feel like it looks sloppy to do this constantly.

```
stop_listening_result = self.listening_port.stopListening()

if isinstance(stop_listening_result, defer.Deferred):
    stop_listening_result.addCallback(self.start)
else:
    self.start()
```

This particular example is calling `stop` on a [`IListeningPort`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IListeningPort.html), which from their documentation says :
`Stop listening on this port.

If it does not complete immediately, will return Deferred that fires upon completion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you want [`maybeDeferred`](https://docs.twisted.org/en/stable/api/twisted.internet.defer.html#maybeDeferred). It will wrap a synchronous result in an already-completed `Deferred`. As the documentation states:

> Invoke a function that may or may not return a Deferred.
>
> Call the given function with the given arguments. If the returned
> object is a Deferred, return it. If the returned object is a Failure,
> wrap it with fail and return it. **Otherwise, wrap it in succeed and
> return it**. If an exception is raised, convert it to a Failure, wrap it
> in fail, and then return it.

Then you can always assume a `Deferred` has been returned:

```
from twisted.internet.defer import maybeDeferred

stop_listening_result = maybeDeferred(self.listening_port.stopListening)
stop_listening_result.addCallback(self.start)
```